# javascript [...str.matchAll() ] return associative array or object

Tags: javascript, arrays

when we using .matchAll() sgainst a string,and reteieve value using spread operator syntax then it return like this ( see on chrome console )

for eg.

```js
const matches = 'abcd bcd a'.matchAll(/(?<name>abc)/gid);

console.log([...matches])
```

```
[
[
  "abc",
  "abc"
]
index: 0, 
input: 'abcd bcd a', 
groups: {…}, 
indices: Array(2)
]
```

although it say array.length is 2 then what are these other property?

is this assiative array like PHP or
this is object or
array because javascript array has numeric value only (AFAIK)
and if it is object then why .length working ?

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays like PHP. It has objects, which are *somewhat* similar to associative arrays, but the keys are strictly strings and there's no "length" to an object.

Comment: does objet have .length property ?

Comment: No, it does not. You can however use `Object.keys()` to get an array of object property names, and then check the length of that.

Comment: but I can execute `.length` and it return 2, that's where confusion is because chrome display it as array  see https://imgur.com/a/NvNBa3Z

Comment: Well you can add a `.length` property to any object you want. An array (which is of course an object) has a `.length` property that automatically tracks the largest *numeric* property name, but it ignores property names that are not numbers.

Comment: Also properties of JavaScript objects can be marked as "not enumerable", which means that they are invisible to things like `for ... in` and `Object.keys()`.  As I said, JavaScript objects really are not associative arrays.

Comment: got you, now the additional query is that how can we find that how many properties are there in such array. if I use `Object.keys()` it return "0", where are the other property which can be accessed but cant be count ?

Comment: Well that's deliberately hard to do. Non-enumerable properties are a feature, so that an object can have methods or properties that are distinct from the "data" part of the object. You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to get *all* the property names *except* properties whose "names" are Symbol instances.

Comment: it returns`['0', 'length']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array that has additional properties.

Arrays are objects in JavaScript. Objects can have arbitrary key-value pairs associated with them. Although arrays *usually* have only numeric-indexed properties plus `.length`, because they're objects, other properties can be added as well. That's [what's happening here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-regexpbuiltinexec).

The `.length` of an array always refers to the number greater than the highest *array index keys*. (so, if an array has indices 0 and 1, its length is 2). Non-array indices are not included in the `.length`.

The following is perfectly valid code as well:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
arr.someProp = 'someVal';
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr.someProp);
```

(That said, *usually*, in well-designed code, you should not manually assign non-numeric indices to arrays; it's unintuitive, as your question shows.)

Comment: Thanks, so how can we count how many additional properties are there ? because wehn we change flag, property count changed

Comment: In general, given an object, you can iterate over all enumerable own keys with `Object.keys(obj)`. For regex matching in particular, you should look at the pattern and the flags to identify (statically) which additional properties there will be.

Comment: Object.keys() give only "0" not any other property

Comment: whis there is no inbuild method (ob object or array ) like `.hasOwnProperty` or `.hasOwn` to get all property which was returned with this output ( not under __prototype__ obviouslly)

Comment: For regex matching in particular, you should look at the pattern and the flags to identify (statically) which additional properties there will be. For the more general situation, given an object, not all properties are enumerable - if you need non-enumerable properties as well, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`

Comment: that is Object method but this is array as chrome says and when run above method, it return `['0', 'length']`

Comment: Arrays are objects. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` can be passed any value, including arrays. The non-array indicies other than `length` aren't own enumerable properties, so they won't be included.

Comment: So it means, we can only access using dot notation, ther are enuumerable propery bit can't be view by any method. Thanks

Comment: No. Both enumerable and non-enumerable properties can be iterated over using `Object.getOwnPropertNames`. Enumerable properties can also be iterated over using `Object.keys`. (If you want to work with both the keys and values, use `Object.entries`. If you want to work with only the values, use `Object.values`)

Comment: Thanks , I am aware about all the object methods you have mkentioned but my real query is still there, I cant get any of these additiona property by any method. can you try and let me know. :)